Error: 'No module named pyimod02_importers' after creating EXE with auto-py-to-exe
I created an EXE file using auto-py-to-exe, but running it throws this error:
Failed to execute script 'pyiboot01_bootstrap': No module named 'pyimod02_importers'  
Module object for pyimod02_importers is NULL!

Project details:
Includes OpenCV, YOLOv3, and Dlib models.
File structure: combined_script.py, yolov3.weights, shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks, etc.
All dependencies are installed in a virtual environment.


Tried so far:
Used --onefile and --onedir options.
Verified all libraries in requirements.txt.

Question:
How can I resolve this pyimod02_importers error and ensure all dependencies are bundled correctly?

This question is similar to: Fatal error detected: Module object for pyimod02_importers is NULL. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
